# Splitting FOR XML into baches

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml-path

I'm pulling a large number of records from our SQL Server database into XML to then be sent to a client. However because of the number of rows (about 6,000) and the amount of fields (about 200 per product) I can successfully get the data but because of its size if I try to write it to screen or send it then an error occurs due to its size (response buffer exceeded).

What I would like to do is split the data into smaller segments, I can think of a way to do it by looping through the response and every 500 or so products splitting it.

But I wanted to know if there would be a way to do it within SQL? My thoughts are that I could use a cursor or by creating a temporary table of ids and then then joining on that, to produce the batches of XML, but to me this seems like it would be quite inefficient.

The simplified SQL I am using:

```
SELECT (
SELECT product_id, sku, title 
FROM products
FOR XML PATH('value'), ROOT('products'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
) as my_xml
```

I would like the record set returned to look like this -

```
+--------+----------------------------+
| Batch  | XML                        |
+--------+----------------------------+
| 1      | <products xmlns xsi= ... > |
| 2      | <products xmlns xsi= ... > |
| 3      | <products xmlns xsi= ... > |
| ...    | ...                        |
+--------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: You could use a loop, yes, but it also sounds like you're trying to display the large XML value(s) on screen; which is why you have the problem. If you need that much data you should be using an ETL process to export the entire XML value to the file system.

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL is how I have gone about splitting it into batches of 500 -

```
SELECT batch, 
    CAST((      
        SELECT 
        product_id, title, sku
        FROM products AS p
        WHERE p.product_id BETWEEN min_id AND max_id
        FOR XML PATH('value'), ROOT('products'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
    ) AS varchar(max)) as product_xml
FROM (
    SELECT 
        MIN(product_id) as min_id,
        MAX(product_id) as max_id,
        batch
    FROM (
        SELECT 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY product_id ASC)/500 AS batch,
          product_id
        FROM products
    ) t
    GROUP BY batch
) t1
ORDER BY batch
```

It runs very quickly and returns the rows I was looking for